# What is the safe way to use transaction isolations in parallel calls in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm having data conflicts with a stored proc which is called concurrently. I have several "engines", each with a unique ID (1 to 5), trying to process packets in a "Inbox" table. I want each packet to be processed once. To retrieve the next packet to process, an engine will call this stored procedure and pass its ID as an argument. The SP must assign a packet to the engine, and return it.

At the high-level the logic is the following:

- Look for the oldest packet in the inbox which isn't being processed by any other engines
- Check if, for the same customer of that packet, another packet exist and is being taken care of by another engine:

  - If that's the case, assign that packet to that engine so all packets for a customer are processed by the same engine, then start again
  - Otherwise, assign that packet to me
- At the end, return the oldest packet assigned to me, if any exists

I set the isolation level in the SP to try and make sure that two concurrent calls to the SP wouldn't result in the same packet returned to different engines. Yet somehow this still happens in rare occasions.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RetrieveNextInboxPacket]
    @engineId int
AS
BEGIN           
    DECLARE @CustId NVARCHAR(7) = NULL;
    DECLARE @PacketID NVARCHAR(255) = NULL;
​
​
    DECLARE @ExistingEngineId INT;
​
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
​
        WHILE @ExistingEngineId IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @CustId = custid, @PacketID = Id 
            FROM Inbox WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE (EngineId IS NULL OR EngineId = @engineId)
            AND ([OnHold] IS NULL OR [OnHold] = 0)
            ORDER BY EngineId DESC, syncdate ASC;
​
            SET @ExistingEngineId = (SELECT TOP 1 EngineId FROM Inbox 
                                        WHERE custid = @Custid 
                                        AND Id != @PacketID 
                                        AND EngineId != @engineId 
                                        AND EngineId IS NOT NULL)
            
            IF @ExistingEngineId IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Inbox SET EngineId = @ExistingEngineId WHERE id = @PacketID
                SET @CustId = NULL 
                SET @PacketID = NULL
                SET @ExistingEngineId = NULL
                
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Inbox SET EngineId = @engineId, SyncStartedOn = GETUTCDATE() 
                WHERE Id = @PacketID;
                SET @ExistingEngineId = 999
                
            END
        END
        
    COMMIT TRANSACTION                      
                     
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Inbox WHERE EngineId = @engineId
    AND ([OnHold] IS NULL OR [OnHold] = 0) 
    ORDER BY syncdate ASC;
    
END
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but I would not use `sp_` in your names. Read [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) for more information

Comment: Youre engine's are calling this procedure ? So it can be called by one engine while it's still busy. I don't think there is an easy way to do that. Maybe you can let all engines write to a single table when they need a new id, and call this code from a trigger on that table. That way you could prevent the code from running 2 times in the same transaction

Comment: Yes @GuidoG it can be called by an engine while it's busy with another one. In that case I'd rather the tables are locked for example, so that I make sure it waits for the execution to finish with one before starting the transaction with the other. Which is what I'm assuming the serializable level does?

Comment: `TABLOCKX` is overkill, `SERIALIZABLE` will sort out everything for you. But why use `WHILE`, you can do this whole thing in a single statement

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, I have the suspicion too that `TABLOCKX` doesn't bring any benefit when using `SERIALIZABLE` from the documentation. 
As per the `WHILE`, I don't see how to do the whole thing without it?

Comment: When you say "process the packet" is there anything being done apart from what is in this code above? And the PK of this table is `PacketID`?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes the `PacketID` is the PK of the table. The engine picking up the packet will read the data, do some calculation and send it to a separate system, so we can assume for the purpose of the question that it's all that is being done here

Comment: So why bother with the whole "assigning to other engines"? Just check there are no other packets for this customer already assigned, and let each engine worry about getting its own packets. Something like this: `UPDATE Inbox SET EngineId = @engineId, SyncStartedOn = GETUTCDATE() OUTPUT inserted.Id WHERE EngineId IS NULL OR EngineId = @engineId AND custid NOT IN (SELECT custid FROM Inbox other WHERE other.Id <> Inbox.Id AND other.EngineId <> @engineId)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Charlieface. I ended up doing something like this, but I'm still wondering what was wrong in the original SP, as it looks like conflicts shouldn't happen anyway in the way the procedure is written...

Comment: Simple answer: locking. You need to use `UPDLOCK` to tell it to hold the lock til the end of the transaction. Even under `SERIALIZABLE` it won't hold a lock from `SELECT` otherwise

Comment: Is the `TABLOCKX` not enough already? or am I confused and it serves a different purpose than `UPDLOCK`?